# Looping through range in descending order

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to work out a code that would loop through a range in descending order. Basically I would like to start with the maximum value, and on the next loop take the second maximum value, and so on.

I'm not sure how to go about this, if it could work with a For Each rng in Range sort of way that would be ideal.

Comment: So sorting first is not an option?

Comment: You could write a function to loop through and find the highest value based on criteria, where criteria is your previously highest value.  You would want to do this with an array to be more efficient... or you can use the "sorting an array" function, which is out there, and use the sorted array to choose a value and `.find` or `.match` and act upon said range.

Comment: Voting to close as `off topic` due to this post being a discussion piece without an objective answer.  If you have a specific question, please edit your post.

Comment: Are the values unique or not?

Comment: what values included in the range?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot use it in a For Each Loop because it will always follow the same pattern. But if you can use For-Next loop: use this code so that it will start on the max value first down to the smallest value

```
For i = 5 To 1 Step -1

MsgBox i

Next i
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking about. OP is asking to loop cellvalues from max to min. That means it does not relate to the row number.